# boss migration 4.3 to 5.1 : ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: ejb, jboss5.x

We are in the Process of migrating jboss 4.3 to jBoss 5.1 We are using EJB 1.1 in the current systems.We fixed a lot of issues to make the server up and finally we are not able to see the Home Page due to Db connection.We are getting Below error:

```
[org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider] (main) Using datasource: java:/oradbds
2012-10-11 18:27:59,493 WARN [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool] (main) Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:225)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:195)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:639).
```

I Guess error may be due to Db connection related Jar like `ojdbc14.jar` which is incompatible for jboss5.1.

Let me know if you need some more info . Please provide a solution.

Comment: O/t, but why do you migrate from an ancient version to a very old version? If you're migrating, why not to the latest version, or if you have a one-version-behind policy the version before that?

Comment: Thanks Mike.We are thinking for higher versions also.Actual idea is we are trying to upgrade to higher version which has minimum Code changes in the application.If we have major code change for Jboss 5.1.We shall move to higher versions..

Answer (score 0):

first of all: which JDK do you use? IMHO you should use JDK 6 and ojdbc6.jar. Why do you want to use your old EJB 1.1 based app?

It seems that the DB-credentials are not correct ...

Best Regards,
Sascha

Comment: Thanks I am using 1.6_0_24 version.Its an old application and we use EJB 1.1,Initially we faced issue to deploy EJB 1.1 in JBOSS 5.1 but we fixed it by repacing the EJB DTD version to 2.0 in the Ejb-jar.xml. The same application is wroking fine in Jboss 4.3.FYI :DB credentials are taken from LDAP.

Comment: OK, how does your connection string to the Oracle-DB look like? Can you log on using a simple Java-application using the same credentials without JBoss? Which driver-class dou you use? Under /docs/examples/jca/ you can find several examples how your Oracle-DS should look like.

Comment: BTW.: You should upgrade to EJB 3.x and Java EE 5 or 6 :-)